# AnyLogic priority-based queue from 3 sources

Tags: anylogic

I have an AnyLogic model with 3 sources that are connected to queue. How can i set to each of the source its Priority(or can it be the obvious parametre?) and what should i write to the field Agent priority(default is zero).[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7Lmf.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to do that you have to create a custom agent with a parameter or variable called priority.

On the source block you define the priority of the agent. For instance:

```
agent.priority=2;
```

and in the queue block you choose the "priority-based" option in the queueing (which is what you did) and you set up the agent priority as agent.priority